# Is there an alarm clock app for Windows (running on a laptop)?

Tags: windows, laptop, alarm

I need to use my laptop computer as an alarm clock. The laptop is specifically an X301 running Vista Enterprise

Features I am looking for in this application, ordered by importance:

2. Will work even if laptop is in sleep mode
3. Is audible even if the OS volume is muted/low (automatically adjusts OS volume)
4. Customizable alarm sound
5. Snooze (with customizable interval)
6. Gradually increases alarm sound

*Sidenote: I usually use the alarm clock on my cell phone, but it was stolen yesterday :(*

Comment: Note that unmuting probably won't work if you muted sound with the volume control buttons on your keyboard. At least on my R60 they're done in hardware and have no relation whatsoever to the volume setting in Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alarm Clock of Justice, Free, http://www.forrestheller.com/alarm2_2/

- Wake from sleep
- "[Backup Alarm] unmutes your volume and sets it to the highest level."
- "Alarms with Music, videos, websites, programs and just about anything can be launched"
- Snooze w/ interval adjust
- "Volume effects can make the system volume fade in and out, be set to a certain level, or be random"

Citrus Alarm Clock, USD 13, http://www.ornj.net/citrus/

- Wake from sleep
- Dunno about unmuting or maxing volume
- "MP3, WMA, and many other media types are supported"
- Snooze, dunno bout interval adjust
- "Fade in alarm audio for relaxed awakening"

Comment: haha, free is a nice feature, too^^

Comment: Citrus Alarm Clock used to be free, if you want an old version

Comment: 20 MB download is amazingly large for a simple alarm clock app, but Alarm Clock of Justice gets the job done. (Also wish there was a default sound if no media file is selected, yet.)

Answer (score 3):

I found this app that says it will wake up a computer from sleep mode.

[PC Alarm Clock](http://www.aquariussoft.com/pc-alarm-clock/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was an alarm clock [power toy for XP Media Center Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/mcepowertoys.mspx) (it won't work on Home or Pro).

...only useful if we know what version of Windows your running.